# ToDo List on Android Studio-Cannot Resolve Method

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I am having trouble creating a task where I long click an item it will delete. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Apparently, this is supposed to be there and I have it declared. Check where I have commented. OnItemLongClicked is not being recognized. That is where I am having trouble. I am new to do this, so please help!

```
package com.example.mysimpletodo;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class itemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<itemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface onLongClickListener {
        void onItemLongClicked(int position);


    }

    List<String> items;
    View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener;

    public itemsAdapter(List<String> items, View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        View todoView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(todoView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String item = items.get(position);
        holder.bind(item);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvItem;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvItem = itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        }

        public void bind(String item) {
            tvItem.setText(item);
            tvItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    longClickListener.OnItemLongClicked(getAdapterPosition());
                            //check for this line again. I have a problem here where OnItemLongClicked is not recognized and stays red. How come it is not recognizing it and it's recognized above.

                    return true;

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `longClickListener.onLongClick(...` - although you may have other issues concerning scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared longClickListener of View Class

> View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener;

In place of View.onLongClickListener lonngClickListenr You should be using

```
itemsAdapter. onLongClickListener longClickListener
```

Comment: Android studio still underlines the onLongClickListener as red. It gives me the same problem as OnItemLongList.

Answer (score 0):

Change your bind Method Signature to:

```
public void bind(String item, final LongClickListener longClickListener) {
        tvItem.setText(item);
        tvItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                longClickListener.onItemLongClicked(getAdapterPosition());

                return true;

            }
        });
    }
```

Your ViewHolder Class does not know your declared longClickListener, if you are not passing it somewhere.

Comment: This does not help, unfortunately, because it is not identifying what LongClickListener is and it is making it red.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong interface to your adapter. It's not needed to pass `View.OnLongClickListener` - you should pass *your* `OnLongClickListener` that you've already made in ItemsAdapter. Don't forget to implement it and then trigger its function `onItemLongClicked`.

Solution in Kotlin style:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ItemsAdapter(internal var items: List<String>, private var longClickListener: OnLongClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private var tvItem: TextView = itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)

        fun bind(item: String) {
            tvItem.text = item
            tvItem.setOnLongClickListener {
                longClickListener.onItemLongClicked(adapterPosition)
                true
            }
        }
    }
}

interface OnLongClickListener {
    fun onItemLongClicked(position: Int)
}
```